# WCF service authenticating incoming SAML from external service

Tags: wcf, authentication, saml

My WCF service will receive incoming SOAP requests containing signed SAML assertions and the only thing I'll have to validate these is a public key given to my by the calling organisation. I want to configure the service to automatically authenticate the incoming request sigs using the public key. I don't have a STS or access to the calling organisations STS.

I've read tonnes of articles on configuring similar, but not this exact scenario. I'd appreciate a link to the right article.

Thanks in advance.